# CoreData - one-to-many modeled relationship comes out as one-to-one

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, one-to-many

I am new to Core Data modeling, and I am having a hard time understanding how one-to-many relationships work.

I have a parent entity called `Task`, which can have several instances of `Comment` entity.  I modeled it like this: on `Comments`, a relationship to `Task` called `task` with the `Task` entity a destination. On `Task`, a relationship called `comments`, with `Comment` as its destination, and both relationships are each others inverse.

Not defining an inverse results in either warnings or error messages. While modeling this way works, I've noticed that once I create a second comment for a given `Task`, the first is replaced (one-to-one relationship).

What would be the correct way to tell the Core Data Model that this relationship allows many comments in one `Task`?

Also, since CoreData seems to manage primary keys on its own, how would I create an `NSPredicate` to retrieve  all comments for a given Task?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all you need to set the `plural` option in the `Task` entity, select it in your `.xdatamodeled` and select the `relationship` property of `Task` entity to `comments` you should be able to see this[image]

there is a `plural` option be sure to check that out. You must recreate your `NSManagedObject` if your using generated classes and also if your using sqlite store you must delete and rebuild so it will not complain about the new schema not being the same with the old one.

To check if you have a one to many relationship your `Task` entity should have a property called comments which is a class type of `NSSet` not Comments.

If you want to retrieve all comments for a given task you need to iterate the `NSSet(comments)` property of that task.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know these options were available. I guess I'd always edited my model with the right pane closed. I am currently not using generated classes other than to test how Core Data names the setters and getters (and the relationships).