# Core Data Entity Relationship like Array inside Entity?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, core-data, entity

So I am making a todo like app. Now I have made the app I want to add a functionality where each task can have subtasks like:

Task: Book Report 
Sub Tasks:
     - Get Information
     - Summarise and Print information
     - Stick information to paper

To clarify I kind of want the core data entity to function as if it were an array.

Now I tried attempting this myself and I did it but what happened was that the when I would add a task and delete the task, the subtasks would still be there.

I am really confused on how I need to setup my entity. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Hope this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280777/coredata-one-to-many-modeled-relationship-comes-out-as-one-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a to-many relationship to another entity and a reciprocal "Inverse" relationship in the child entity.

Check this out:

http://timroadley.com/2012/02/19/core-data-basics-part-4-relationships/

Inverse relationships must be created in the model editor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have successfully created a to-many relationship in my project but I did not get what you meant by 'a reciprocal relationship in the child entity.'

Comment: The link is dead. That's why you should not use external links