# iOS persistent store options

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

would like to ask for the community's suggestions.
I need a persistent store in my iOS app.
I have considered Core Data and SQLite and both are not ideal for the following reasons.

**Core Data:**

- unable to model certain object relationships, such as Object A has a one-to-many relationship with NSString.

//Added:

- unable to model a Dictionary(or map) as an attribute for a one-to-one relationship. i.e. Object A has a one-to-one relationship to Object B (and Object B behaves like a dictionary)

**SQLite:**

- poor interface for schema management
- no clean and elegant solution for data migration between schema versions

//Added:

- unable to model a Dictionary(or map) as an attribute for a one-to-one relationship. i.e. Object A has a one-to-one relationship to Object B (and Object B behaves like a dictionary)

the persistent store has to be able to support search. If anyone can suggest ways to circumvent the problems, that would help too.

Comment: CoreData 1:many: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280777/coredata-one-to-many-modeled-relationship-comes-out-as-one-to-one

Answer (score 1):

Based on your limited description, Core Data would work just fine.  Core Data can easily do one to many relationships.  No matter what technology that you use, you still need table to table (SQLite) or Object to Object (Core Data) relationships.  Nothing is going to give you an Object to String relationship.

You can do Object A to Object B where Object B has only one property which happens to be a string.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i think it can work. I have just thought of additional requirements i need to support and added them. appreciate your input on them as well